# I'm trying to populate a tableview with a list of users, but the tableview will not load anything

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

For some reason I keep getting back a blank tableview. It is showing a query is being loaded from Parse, it just isn't displaying any results. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class userViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {


    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true

    }
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        println(query)
        return query
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var userCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2") as! PFTableViewCell!

        if userCell == nil {
            userCell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell2")
        }

        if let lastName = object["lastName"] as? String {
            var firstName = object["firstName"] as? String
            userCell?.textLabel?.text = "\(lastName), \(firstName)"

        }
        if let adminStatus = object["adminStatus"] as? Bool {
            if adminStatus == true {
            userCell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Administrative Privliges"
            }else{
            userCell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Non Administrative Privliges"
            }
        }

        return userCell
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not initializing the class properly, you need to set the name of the class you want to query

```
// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "yourClass"

    self.textKey = "yourObject"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}
```

I hope this code helps you